# Изменение размеров страницы в зависимости от разрешения

Tags: jquery

Усилиями участников сайта, немного понял, куда копать в правке кода. В общем переписал под jQuery. Но код не работает... Что я не правильно сделал? Подскажите.

***апд***
**Проблема решена совсем другим способом. Всем спасибо.**

```
function hide_div() {
    //var rnd_200 = Math.round(Math.random()*4) + 7; swap_img('loader_' + rnd_200);
    clearTimeout(show_delay);
    show_delay = null;
    if (!obj_float_div) return;
    obj_float_div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    obj_float_div.style.left = "-3000px";
    obj_float_div = false;
}

var IE = (document.all);
var NC = (document.layers);
var Opera = (document.getElementById);

function getWidth() {
    if (IE) return document.body.clientWidth;
    if (NC) return window.innerWidth;
    if (Opera) return document.body.offsetWidth;
    return 1024;
}

var cmw;
var hfw;
var ww;

function recount() {
    var ttt;
    if (window.getSize().x >= 1690) {
        ttt = 8;
    } else if (window.getSize().x >= 1260) {
        ttt = 6;
    } else {
        ttt = 4;
    }
    cmw = ttt * 205;
    hfw = cmw - 5;
    ww = hfw + 30;
}

window.onload = resizecontent;
window.onresize = resizecontent;

function resizecontent() {
    recount();
    $('#header').css({
        'width': hfw + 'px'
    });
    $('#footer').css({
        'width': hfw + 'px'
    });
    if ($('#contentmain').length > 0) {
        $('#contentmain').css({
            'width': cmv + 'px'
        });
    } else {
        $('#wrapper').css({
            'width': ww
        });
    }
    if ($('#imagezoom_overlay').length > 0) {
        $('#imagezoom_overlay').width(document.body.clientWidth);
        $('#imagezoom_overlay').height(window.innerHeight().y);
    }
}
```

*текст курсивом*

Comment: Что должен делать этот код?

Comment: Он ресайзит страницу в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

Comment: Вам, насколько я помню, вчера уже решали эту проблему....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Он ресайзит страницу в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

С этого и надо было начинать.

```
var w = $(window);
w.resize(function(){
    $('body').css({
        width: w.width() + 'px',
        height: w.height() + 'px'
    });
}).resize();
```

А если надо растягивать на всю ширину экрана, а не окна, используйте стандартный объект screen.

Comment: Хм. Т.е. я удаляю свой код полностью и вставляю только этот?

Просто у меня на сайте выводятся картинки подряд. Размер картинок 200х200.

Код, который я первый раз запостил здесь:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/78288/переделать-код-под-jquery

работал на mootools, в вот на jquery не работал.

Comment: Т.к. картинки на сайте размером 200 на 200, в этом коде я так понимаю имеются значения ttt. Если разрешение x>=1690, то cmw=ttt*205; и т.д.

Вообще запутался...

Comment: Поэтому мне надо переделать код, который я запостил.. Но не получается. Какие только можно значения перепробовал.

Comment: var cmw;
    var hfw;
    var ww;
    
    function recount() {
        var ttt;
        if (window.getSize().x >= 1690) {
            ttt = 8;
        } else if (window.getSize().x >= 1260) {
            ttt = 6;
        } else {
            ttt = 4;
        }
        cmw = ttt * 205;
        hfw = cmw - 5;
        ww = hfw + 30;
    }

Исправляю на:

Comment: Вы вообще ссылку [http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow][1] читали?

[1]:http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Comment: На вот это:

    function recount()
    {
        var ttt;
        if ($(document.body.clientWidth().x>=1690)
        {
            ttt = 8;
        }
        else if ($(document.body.clientWidth().x>=1260)
        {
            ttt = 6;
        }
        else
        {
            ttt = 4;
        }
        cmw=ttt*205;
        hfw=cmw-5;
        ww=hfw+30;
    }

Comment: Не работает...

Comment: Читал и даже исправил исходя из этой ссылки. Запостил после коммента.

Даже пробовал исправлять
document.body.clientWidth 
 на
window.innerWidth

Я уже неделю вожусь с этим.. Все перепробовал.

Comment: Проблема решена совсем другим способом. Всем спасибо.